Is there an API or method to pull token holder info in Python
I want to get the holders of a token or an API which provides common token holders of 2 or more tokens. is there an API which I can use to get holder information for all tokens for which I can run a 'common' script or some API which gives me the common holder info?

I think this might answer your question https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/13799/1708

This question is similar to: Retrieving all holders of a given token. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
